# Any 'cat' colorized tool?

Tags: software-rec, syntax-highlighting, pager

I sometimes `cat` a c file or a JSON file, there is no colorful format text.
Is there any command line tool that can show colorful format text as it is in ex: gedit?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/117841/when-reading-a-file-with-less-or-more-how-can-i-get-the-content-in-colors

Comment: The solution seems to open a `vi`, in this way, I think I can use `vim` directly.

Comment: Strange. I just installed and tested. I don't know how you do it, but my `less` now colorizes output? `vi` doesn't open. There's also a SO posting specifically for [colorizing cat with pygments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851134/syntax-highlighting-colorizing-cat). EDIT tested that, and yes, `ccat` produces colorized output.

Comment: sorry, maybe it is not using `vi`, just use a new window to display.

Comment: I think `pygmentize` solved this issue, thanks.

Comment: Happy to be of help :-)

Comment: Look at bat https://github.com/sharkdp/bat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TThe Several Linux commands:

**Pygmentize:** https://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/

**Highlight:** http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php

**Ccat:** https://github.com/jingweno/ccat

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers. The intent behind this site is to become a repository of answers for future reference in case the original source goes away.

Comment: OK.  Got it. You are right.